# Add a data source to Dremio

Tags: dremio

I tried to add a data source to Dremio which is a PostgreSQL database.

the data base called "university-session1", and this is the message it displays: "Could not connect to university-session1, check your JDBC connection information and credentials."
Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: did you verify all the credentials are correct by trying to connect with a different client using the same credentials?